# show * when field not valid

Tags: html, validation, breeze

I am at level 0 in breeze so bear with me. I dont want any ready made code as of now. I am using breeze and want to do client side validation. What i want is to show "*" near html input if data entered is not valid. Below is my code to bind to data returned from breeze.

```
               <td > <input data-bind="value: Name" /></td>
```

How can i achieve this using breeze? Please do let me know if there any live example i can refer to.
I tried googling but couldnt find any examples.

Comment: Although this has nothing to do with breeze and doesn't answer the question, please keep in mind that you'll need to perform server-side validation too as client-side validation is only for user-friendlyness purpose.

Comment: @Bartdude can you give me good example so its easy for me to implement

Comment: Nope, I can't as I don't know anything about breeze. But I do know that server-side validation is the only one that really matters when talking about websites data-integrity.

Comment: I take it you're using knockout for data-binding. Please correct me if I'm wrong. You can achieve what you want using both breeze validator http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/validation and knockout

Comment: @AdelSal i need live example as i have read that documentation

Comment: If you want a live example you need to build a fiddle showing what you have so it can be added on top of that.  Asking for others to write code for you is discouraged and makes it difficult for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Not breeze, but pure JS might help?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            span.red { color:red; }
        </style>
        <script>
            function ValidateFields() {
                //usually use regex to check phones, this is only example.
                // test if value is '123456' in this example.
                if ('123456' == document.getElementById('inpPhone').value) {
                    document.getElementById('spnPhoneValid').innerHTML = '';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('spnPhoneValid').innerHTML = '*';
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        Phone Number (Only 123456):<input id='inpPhone' onchange='ValidateFields();'> <span class='red' id='spnPhoneValid'>*</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

And of course it's for the client's usability and not instead of server-side validation!

Comment: Yes this approach i know but i want to do it using breeze. But many thanks for your answer. I give +1

Answer (score 0):

Breeze **IS NOT** a tool for making html/css modifications to the page view. Breeze knows nothing about DOM.